# Multiply first column by variable depending on unit

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have `du -sh` output saved to txt file:

```
2.1G    /home/x/sample/2GB/
101M    /home/x/sample/100MB/
...
```

What I want is to multiply each value in the first column by a value taken from variable depending on the unit. So if for instance unit is G then multiply by $G and append the the result at the end of each line. How to do this in Bash?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to get the bytes, so instead of using `-h` (which is a shortcut for `--human-readable`), just don't use it.

`du -s` will get you the summarized byte count.